# Ruby on Rails model Confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I came across the following code which is beyond my understating. I'm working hard to grasp it completely from previous 3 days but couldn't.

```
class TestUser < ActiveRecord::Base
   self.table_name = 'garden'

   belongs_to :account
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :garden
```

The entire above code is not understandable for me.

Comment: which code you are not understanding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class TestUser < ActiveRecord::Base
   self.table_name = 'garden'
   authenticates_with_sorcery!

   belongs_to :account
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :garden
```

Breaking it down line by line:

```
class TestUser < ActiveRecord::Base
```

This is defining a class called `TestUser` which is inherited from `ActiveRecord::Base`. All models in rails connected to active record (i.e. having a database table) have the same signature. Inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base` provide `TestUser` model with some magical abilities. Read more about it at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html

```
self.table_name = 'garden'
```

This line is saying that the table that `TestUser` model should connect to is `garden`. By default `TestUser` model is linked to `test_users` table. 
This line is changing that behavior.

Actually, it should be `gardens` as all table names should be plural; `gardens` table is for storing information about many garden objects.

Read about `table_name` at http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods/table_name

```
authenticates_with_sorcery!
```

This line says the system uses [sorcery](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery) gem for authentication. Learn more about it at  http://railscasts.com/episodes/283-authentication-with-sorcery

```
belongs_to :account
```

This line is saying that the `TestUser` object has a `belongs_to` relationship with `Account` model. With this relationship in place, you can find a `test_user's` account with the `test_user.account` method. This is assuming `test_user` is an instance of `TestUser` model. i.e. `test_user = TestUser.new`. Read more about `belongs_to` association at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :garden
```

This line says that you can save attributes on `Garden` object when you are saving a `TestUser` object. Read more about `accepts_nested_attributes_for` at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Finally a piece of advice to help you understand everything better in rails world: Go through a thorough rails tutorial to get a good understanding of rails concepts. The freely available Rails Tutorial book at https://www.railstutorial.org/book is highly recommended.